# how to automatically stop a video?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

on the page there is a component of the slider. it consists of pictures and one slide with video. for the slide that is now shown is isActive = true. How can I automatically stop a video if it is on a slide that is not visible right now?

video component:
`<video id="video" src={video} className={styles.video} loop muted autoPlay playsInline/>`

Comment: what slider are you using?

Comment: This is the slider we wrote ourselves with the team

Comment: then go rational => hook into the event/function where the item is set to inactive and pause the video https://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_met_pause.asp